# Thread.join - Main thread won't resume execution

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm facing this issue. I want my main thread to resume its execution only when other threads complete their execution. But my main thread is not executing even if other threads have done with their execution.

My code is as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private TextView mTextView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_test);

       TestLocalHost th = new TestLocalHost();
       Thread exe = new Thread(th);
       exe.start();

       try {
          exe.join();
       } 
       catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

       mTextView.setText("MainThread");
}

private class TestLocalHost implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        final String s = JSONParser.doGet("http://<My system ip>/GetResult.ashx?op=getInfo",null);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                mTextView.setText(s);

             }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm setting the value of `mTextView` with a value from `exe` thread. I need my main thread overwrite the `mTextView` with `"Main thread"` after it executes. I used a `join()` function to `exe` thread which will ensures main thread will wait till this thread completes execution. But once this thread completes exectuion my main thread is not writing into `mTextView`. What mistake am I doing?

Comment: the join will block completely the UI thread until your thread dies, and nobody can assure you that the Runnable you posted on the blocked ui thread, is going to be processed before or after `mTextView.setText("MainThread");`

Comment: @blackbelt thanks for the concept.In that case what approach should I be following? In real I want the runnable part to execute first and only after runnable completes execution should the main thread continue i.e mTextView.setText("Main Thread")

Comment: I usually use the delegate pattern, to let threads notify their status.

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with how `runOnUiThread` works.

In android, the main thread has a `Looper`. That `Looper` holds a queue of runnable to run, one at a time.

When you call `runOnUiThread`, the `Runnable` is enqueued to the looper, meaning it will be executed after the current thing being run by the looper is done, and the queue is empty.

In your case, the Looper is executing `onCreate` when you call `join`. That means that your `runOnUiThread` will be enqueued for after that.

In terms of sequencing, that means that the following order of calls issue:

- onCreate
- start
- doGet
- runOnUiThread (end of thread)
- setText (in onCreate) (end of onCreate)
- setText (in runOnUiThread)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the "*main thread not writing into `mTextView`*" is that `Thread exe` terminates earlier than the one started by the `runOnUiThread()` method. And since `join()` waits only for `Thread exe` to finish (not the other one), you appearentely get *"MainThread"* of `mTextView` overwritten with *String s* set on the other thread.

You can check it by, for example, seeing `Log`:

```
...
mTextView.setText("MainThread");
Log.d("THREAD", mTextView.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using AsyncTask. It is meant for exactly this purpose.

```
private class GetDataFromNetwork extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         //Get Data using url
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     //Update UI Here. This runs on the UI Thread. 

 }
}
```